# MongoDb, Convert UUID to string, in projection

Tags: mongodb, uuid

I’m looking for a solution to convert a UUID to a string using projection. I’ve tried many different ways, but none of them are working.

[image]

The stranger thing is that Metabase displays the ID correctly, but I cannot manipulate this data because it’s not in string format.

[image]
Have you any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Benjamin

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rickhg12hs

Thank you a lot, your answer help me !

But in my case my Id was  **BinData 3**

```
{
  "_id": BinData(3, "OyQRAeK7QlWMr0E2xWapYg==")
}
```

I refactor your answer as follow :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_idUUIDstr": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function convert(s){let t=s.hex();var r=t.substr(6,2)+t.substr(4,2)+t.substr(2,2)+t.substr(0,2),u=t.substr(10,2)+t.substr(8,2),b=t.substr(14,2)+t.substr(12,2),e=t.substr(16,16);return t=r+u+b+e,t.substr(0,8)+'-'+t.substr(8,4)+'-'+t.substr(12,4)+'-'+t.substr(16,4)+'-'+t.substr(20,12)}",
          "args": [
            "$_id"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and is work perfectly

RESULT

```
[
  {
    "_id": BinData(3, "OyQRAeK7QlWMr0E2xWapYg=="),
    "_idUUIDstr": "0111243b-bbe2-5542-8caf-4136c566a962"
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/qf7e5d2aA41

Comment: `Bindata 3`, I believe, is the format used with CSUUIDs. Excellent answer, btw, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I hope there is a better answer as I consider this very fragile since it depends on JavaScript execution being enabled on the MongoDB server and a fixed `toString` representation of `BinData` UUID.  Until there is something better, perhaps this is *good enough*.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_idUUIDstr": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(x) {return x.toString().slice(6,-2)}",
          "args": ["$_id"],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example document:

```json
{
  "_id": BinData(4, "OyQRAeK7QlWMr0E2xWapYg==")
}
```

Example output:

```json
{
  "_id": BinData(4, "OyQRAeK7QlWMr0E2xWapYg=="),
  "_idUUIDstr": "3b241101-e2bb-4255-8caf-4136c566a962"
}
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0S3YJodtDVB).