# MongoDB: convert and concat UUIDs in an array

Tags: mongodb, uuid, projection

Context: based on fields in a profile array entry I may project few different links.
In order to save the space I want to be able to generate them in a aggregation's projection stage.

I have the following document:

```
{
    "_id": 123,
    "userName": "foo",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "profileId": 345,
            "hash": UUID("5273a20c-f506-4a54-aaf4-ae67a06028c5"),
        },
        {
            "profileId": 456,
            "hash": UUID("f540873f-b489-49b5-b027-ab92d91bea3c"),
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to create the following projection:

```
{
    "userName": "foo",
    "profiles": [
        {
            "linkA": "https://foo/profiles/345/full_5273a20cf5064a54aaf4ae67a06028c5",
            "linkB": "https://foo/profiles/345/summary",
        },
        {
            "linkA": "https://foo/profiles/456/full_f540873fb48949b5b027ab92d91bea3c",
            "linkB": "https://foo/profiles/456/summary",
        },
    ]

}
```

or

```
{
    "userName": "foo",
    "profiles": [
        "https://foo/profiles/345/full_5273a20cf5064a54aaf4ae67a06028c5",
        "https://foo/profiles/456/full_f540873fb48949b5b027ab92d91bea3c",
    ]

}
```

I was trying to build a projection, but I was not able neither concat nor convert UUID. There is a workaround (below to use JS, but I'm not sure it's efficient). This not entire query (just conversion part):

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
{ $match: {profiles: { $exists: true, $not: { $size: 0 }} }},
{ $project: {
    userName: 1,
    profiles: {
        $map: {
            input: "$profiles",

            // "code" : 16702, $concat only supports strings, not binData
            // in: {$concat: ["$$this.hash"]}

            // "code" : 241, Unsupported conversion from binData to string in $convert with no onError value
            // in: { $toString: "$$this.hash" }

            // solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804105/mongodb-convert-uuid-to-string-in-projection
            in: {
                "$function": {
                "body": "function convert(s){let t=s.hex();var r=t.substr(6,2)+t.substr(4,2)+t.substr(2,2)+t.substr(0,2),u=t.substr(10,2)+t.substr(8,2),b=t.substr(14,2)+t.substr(12,2),e=t.substr(16,16);return t=r+u+b+e,t.substr(0,8)+'-'+t.substr(8,4)+'-'+t.substr(12,4)+'-'+t.substr(16,4)+'-'+t.substr(20,12)}",
                "args": [
                    "$$this.hash"
                ],
                "lang": "js"
                }
            }

        }
    },
},
}
])
```

I prepared a playground here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/XG-PO9Sxve3
but I am not 100% if this is internal UUIDv4 representation.

This is how I see another document in mongosh:

```
(...)
profiles: [
    {
      profileId: Long("41060024"),
      hash: new UUID("af7a0e53-1cba-ca19-ef07-cffc5e9bad17"),
      createdAt: ISODate("2023-09-25T21:41:30.451Z")
    }
  ]
```

Do you have any suggestion how to properly do that?

I have seen a similar question/answer here:
[MongoDb, Convert UUID to string, in projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804105/mongodb-convert-uuid-to-string-in-projection)

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dKxx2gWmooQ

I don't believe this is the right approach. As for now I see a workaround to store UUIDs as strings, but maybe there is more elegant way to do that.